# Can I change the node name of a deployed pod?

Tags: openshift

In openshift is there a way I can specify a deployment node to run on?

I tried to go into the front end, stop my pod and then change the yaml to have a different node name...

nodeName: ip-10-9999-999-999.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal

and also hostIP....

hostIP: 10.999.999.999

But it would not let me do this. What's the best way for me to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot influence the node by changing the pod directly. Have a look at DaemonSets instead as one way of controlling placement.

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/daemonsets.html

Answer (score 1):

You can very well control the pod placement by labeling the node/nodes and then while creating a project you can define the label using the --node-selector option.